# Could base class attribute be triggered first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, attributes, polymorphism

It looks like in .NET base class attributes are triggered after Attributes that belong to inherited classes. Seems off to me or am I doing something wrong ?.

All classes in my application inherit from a base class with  `[AuthorizationAttribute]` but only some classes have `[LoggingAttribute]`.
When I'm accessing a method in HomeController, why does my  `[LoggingAttribute]` gets hit before Authorization and how can I trigger base class authorization attribute first and Logging second ?

```
[AuthorizationAttribute]
public class BaseController 
{
  //....class methods
}

[LoggingAttribute]
public class HomeController: BaseController 
{
  //....class methods
}
```

Attributes:

```
 public class AuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
     //...API token gets parsed into Id/Pw 
    }

    public class LoggingAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
     //...Logging record saved with Id/pw established above
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, since it is about authorization, make sure to derive your custom `AuthorizationAttribute` from [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) or implement `IAuthorizationFilter`.

Authorization filters get executed prior to action filter attributes.

This guarantees that controller action methods only get executed when authorized.

Comment: You're right, IAuthorizationFilter inheritance really did enable the Base class attribute to be hit first but I have absolutely no need for this extra logic and it looks that the included interface ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync() method requires for a HttpResponseMessage to be returned that's being built elsewhere. Rebuilding this would be a huge overhaul. Any other suggestions exist ?

Comment: @InspiredBy You might give it a try setting the `Order` explicitly; e.g. `[AuthorizationAttribute(Order=1)]` and `[LoggingAttribute(Order=2)]` - never tried it myself.

Comment: @InspiredBy Wondering why not inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute`; there's only a `bool` to return from [AuthorizeCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_AuthorizeAttribute_AuthorizeCore_System_Web_HttpContextBase).